# how to implement EF inner join with given filter?

Tags: entity-framework

```
SELECT DISTINCT k.* FROM [dbo].[kinds] K 
INNER JOIN KindGraphic KG ON K.KindId = KG.KindId
INNER JOIN Graphics G ON KG.GraphicId = G.GraphicId
WHERE K.CategoryType = 2
AND G.IsSpecial = 1
```

How to write this in EF ? I am new to EF.  I m using dbContex for my MVC project.

> Make Note that "KindGraphic" table is mapped liked this ways

so I can not use this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/21986882/3264939

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Kind>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Graphics)
                .WithMany(g => g.Kinds)
                .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("KindId")
                    .MapRightKey("GraphicId")
                    .ToTable("KindGraphic"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result from your original query is some kind of complex result. So without selecting the exact columns (instead of using `*`), I assume the result is contained in an anonymous type like this:

```
{
    Kind,        
    Graphic
}
```

I understand that `KindGraphic` is some kind of junction (join) table, so it's info is not important to include in the result (we can access `KindId` from `Kind` and `GraphicId` from `Graphic`). Here is the LINQ query:

```
var result = context.kinds.Where(e => e.CategoryType == 2)
                    .SelectMany(e=> e.Graphics.Where(g=>g.IsSpecial == 1), 
                                (e, g) => new { Kind = e, Graphic = g} );
```

After your edit to use `distinct`, the query can be translated as you want all `kinds` having category type = `2` and any Graphics with `IsSpecial = 1`. So it should be like this:

```
var result = context.kinds.Where(e => e.CategoryType == 2 && 
                                      e.Graphics.Any(g=>g.IsSpecial == 1));
```

Comment: Kindly check updated question , I have update my question. sorry for missing main point. I just needs data from kinds

Comment: @user5206903 that does not make sense to me because then you have duplicated data from `kinds`. If you want that any way, just replace `new {...}` with `e`.

Comment: @user5206903 see my edit (after you made your edit of using `disctinct`), also you should have notified me about the edit so that I could update my answer (in case I did not think there was any change in the question).